# Cannot click on TableView cell. (iOS, Custom cell implementation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a table view with list of article titles. I have implemented functions that will delete and archive those articles by swipes (left swipe - archive, right swipe - delete). It works great (like application called "Clear" on iPhone). 
Then, I have been dragged from a cell (holding ctrl button) to new view controller (where I have label, imageview and textview) to display the article (push). However, somehow cells are not clickable. I can do swipes with no problem, but cannot click and go to next view controller. I have used `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` for setting data to display. Also, I used tutorial to configure cell. I have included implementation for that as well. I suppose, that is where the problem, but I do not know how the code, for configuring cell works. What is the cause of such behaviour? Thank you.

The Code for InboxViewController.m (The one which has tableview):

```
 . . .

#pragma mark view
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    [self.db openDatabase];
    NSString* date_added = [self.db getLastArticleDate];
    [self makeConnetion:(id)date_added];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear: self.articles: %d", self.articles.count);
    [self.db closeDatabase];



}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[SHCTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Content"];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: self.articles: %d", self.articles.count);
    return self.articles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Content";
    SHCTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //NSMutableArray* safeArticles = self.articles;
    // Configure the cell...
    Article* article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *listingKey = article.title;
    NSString *listingValues = article.url;
    cell.textLabel.text = listingKey;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = listingValues ;
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.todoItem = article;
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark cell atributes
-(UIColor*)colorForIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    NSUInteger itemCount = self.articles.count - 1;
    float val = ((float)index / (float)itemCount) * 0.6;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green:val blue: 0.0 alpha:1.0];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70.0f;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndex:indexPath.row];
}


#pragma mark TODO delete from server database
//method to delete an article form view and to call method to delete from database, as well as form server database
-(void)deleteArticle:(Article*)articleToDelete {
   . . .
}

#pragma mark TODO archive in server database
//method to delete an article form view and to call method to delete from database, as well as form server database
-(void)archiveArticle:(Article*)articleToArchive {

   . . .

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ArticleView"]) {
        ArticleViewController* articleView = (ArticleViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
        Article *article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:index];
        articleView.article_title.text = article.title;
        articleView.article_content.text = article.content;
    }
}
```

SHCTableViewCell.m (configures cell)

```
//
//  SHCTableViewCell.m
//  ClearStyle
//
//  Created by Fahim Farook on 23/9/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 RookSoft Pte. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SHCTableViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation SHCTableViewCell {
    CAGradientLayer* _gradientLayer;
    CGPoint _originalCenter;
    BOOL _deleteOnDragRelease;
    CALayer *_itemCompleteLayer;
    BOOL _markCompleteOnDragRelease;
    UILabel *_tickLabel;
    UILabel *_crossLabel;
}

const float UI_CUES_MARGIN = 20.0f;
const float UI_CUES_WIDTH = 50.0f;

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // add a tick and cross
        _tickLabel = [self createCueLabel];
        _tickLabel.text = @"Archive";
        _tickLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [self addSubview:_tickLabel];
        _crossLabel = [self createCueLabel];
        _crossLabel.text = @"Delete";
        _crossLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [self addSubview:_crossLabel];

        // create a label that renders the todo item text

        // remove the default blue highlight for selected cells
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        // add a layer that overlays the cell adding a subtle gradient effect
        _gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        _gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor]];
        _gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0];

        // add a layer that renders a green background when an item is complete
        _itemCompleteLayer = [CALayer layer];
        _itemCompleteLayer.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.6 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
        _itemCompleteLayer.hidden = YES;
        [self.layer insertSublayer:_itemCompleteLayer atIndex:0];

        // add a pan recognizer
        UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

const float LABEL_LEFT_MARGIN = 20.0f;

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // ensure the gradient layers occupies the full bounds
    _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    _itemCompleteLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    _tickLabel.frame = CGRectMake(-UI_CUES_WIDTH - UI_CUES_MARGIN, 0,
                                  UI_CUES_WIDTH, self.bounds.size.height);
    _crossLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width + UI_CUES_MARGIN, 0,
                                   UI_CUES_WIDTH, self.bounds.size.height);
}

-(void)setTodoItem:(Article *)todoItem {
    _todoItem = todoItem;
    // we must update all the visual state associated with the model item
    //_label.text = todoItem.text;
    _itemCompleteLayer.hidden = !todoItem.completed;
}

// utility method for creating the contextual cues
-(UILabel*) createCueLabel {
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return label;
}

#pragma mark - horizontal pan gesture methods
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[self superview]];
    // Check for horizontal gesture
    if (fabsf(translation.x) > fabsf(translation.y)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // if the gesture has just started, record the current centre location
        _originalCenter = self.center;
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // translate the center
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
        self.center = CGPointMake(_originalCenter.x + translation.x, _originalCenter.y);
        // determine whether the item has been dragged far enough to initiate a delete / complete
        _markCompleteOnDragRelease = self.frame.origin.x > self.frame.size.width / 2;
        _deleteOnDragRelease = self.frame.origin.x < -self.frame.size.width / 2;
        // Context cues
        // fade the contextual cues
        float cueAlpha = fabsf(self.frame.origin.x) / (self.frame.size.width / 2);
        _tickLabel.alpha = cueAlpha;
        _crossLabel.alpha = cueAlpha;

        // indicate when the item have been pulled far enough to invoke the given action
        _tickLabel.textColor = _markCompleteOnDragRelease ?
        [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
        _crossLabel.textColor = _deleteOnDragRelease ?
        [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // the frame this cell would have had before being dragged
        CGRect originalFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y,
                                          self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
        if (!_deleteOnDragRelease) {
            // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                             animations:^{
                                 self.frame = originalFrame;
                             }
             ];
        }
        if (_deleteOnDragRelease) {
            // notify the delegate that this item should be deleted
            [self.delegate deleteArticle:self.todoItem];
        }
        if (!_markCompleteOnDragRelease) {
            // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                             animations:^{
                                 self.frame = originalFrame;
                             }
             ];
        }
        if (_markCompleteOnDragRelease) {
            // mark the item as complete and update the UI state
            self.todoItem.completed = YES;
            [self.delegate archiveArticle:self.todoItem];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: can you just try it after disabling the gesture recognizer given in the SHCTableViewCell.

Comment: Hi, it does not work if I do that either.I will try method by @007 . Thank you for suggestion anyway.

Comment: Your thinking was right, I have commented whole implementation of SHCTableViewCell and now, I can select a cell (it gets highlight with grey). But still, it does not go to other view. So, part of the problem probably in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tableview delegate method if you want any action after clicking tableview cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    NSLog(@"selected cell");
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does output "selected cell", but there is no visual indication that cell is selected and I need to forward data to new view, and pop up new view. Is that possible to do with this method? Thank you.

Comment: first you should be clear about your doubt, do you want some animation  on selecting cells.